# Ignore message "Breakpoint x at y" after setting a breakpoint in gdb

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to disable the message "Breakpoint x at y" after setting a breakpoint in gdb? Example:

```
Breakpoint 1248 at 0x10054700          
<function, no debug info> func;
```

I'm setting breakpoints for every function in the file and I want to omit these messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways.

You can use the `set logging` commands to redirect output to `/dev/null`.  Then set your breakpoints, and then reset the logging.

Or, you can evaluate the commands via Python using `gdb.execute`, and use the `to_string` parameter of that function to redirect the output to a string -- and then ignore the return value of this function.